# How to convert iptables to nftables

Tags: iptables, nftables

I need to use `nftables`, instead of `iptables`.

How can I convert the following to `nftables` format instead of `iptables`?

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination "y.y.y.y"
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination "z.z.z.z"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: What version of Linux are you using where the nftables installation dos not provide the backward compatibility shim? Or is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
nft add rule nat prerouting tcp dport 22 dnat y.y.y.y
nft add rule nat prerouting dnat z.z.z.z
nft add rule nat postrouting masquerade
```

Comment: Got this error:

nft add rule nat prerouting tcp dport 22 dnat 185.XX.XX.XX
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
add rule nat prerouting tcp dport 22 dnat 185.XX.XX.XX

Hide the IP for security reason

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your question with the result of `nft list ruleset` so I can understand why?